# Fluke Etherscope stuck at loading kernel, Have JTAG Pins, and bootloader access

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, debugging, gdb

I had purchased two Fluke Etherscopes, these are stuck with the message 'Loading Kernel' on the screen. I was able to get a serial console, and access the bootloader using the serial port on the side of the device. I can access the bootloader (Intrinsyc Bootloader) and have tried to use the update files to install a new kernel. It installs successfully to the flash memory, and then tries to boot. I have tried to pass kernel boot parameters through the boot command, and get no output what so ever. I have successfully identified the JTAG pins, except for the nTRST pin, pretty sure I know which pin, but showing a diode between the pad and the suspected pin.

I have flashed the Black Magic Probe firmware and bootloader to my STM32F104 development board, it has a logic level of 3.3v, and so does the CPU. I know which pins to attach the BMP to, but I am not sure where to go from here. I have tried looking for information on debugging the Linux kernel through JTAG, and GDB, but nothing that I see as very clear. I found multiple firmware update files for this device, and also found some source code, both on a public fluke ftp site. I have tried to contact Fluke for service information, and they told me to reach out to NetScout, who say that Fluke never gave them that information. I am attaching the serial printout from when I press the power button to where it stops outputting and just shows the loading kernel screen. I would like to at least get an idea of what I can research in order to get either debug output to the serial console, or debug output through the JTAG port and the BMP firmware. The CPU is the Intel XScale PXA255.

I know that when a CF card is inserted with a file with the name 'ZIMAGE', it tries to load it as a 'Debug Kernel' into RAM, and then points to it for execution. If there is anymore information I can give anyone, please let me know. I bought these devices broken so that I can learn while trying to fix them, and would really like to get them up and running. Again, any information I can pass along, please let me know and I will post it.

Thank you all for your time.

**Serial Output from Boot:**

```
**************************************************
** Intrinsyc Bootloader (IBoot)                 **
** Copyright 2001,2002 Intrinsyc Software Inc.  **
** Version: 2.0                                 **
** Support: http://www.intrinsyc.com            **
**************************************************
Enabling LCD controller
Setting Registers in the EPSON Controller!!
Finished Setting Registers in the EPSON Controller!!
MCMEM0 : 0x0002449D
MCATT0 : 0x0002449D
MCIO0  : 0x00014290
MECR   : 0x00000000
MCCR : 0x00000001
GPLR0 : CFF79FFD
PCMCIA Detected 0 Slots.
setup def img : Image Offset : 70
Image Size X : 294 Y : 70
img done
Loading TXRX Xilinx.
TXRX Xilinx Complete.
reseting PHY
We Should Auto Negociate
Phy Control Register = 0x0000FFFF
Phy ID Register one = 0x0000FFFF
Phy ID Register two = 0x0000FFFF
Phy STAT Register = 0x0000FFFF
Xilinx TXRX Reg : 0x003C3B3C
Leaving init_ethernet
IBoot> help
boot, bootmem, copy, crc, createfis, decode, download,
eraseflash, exec, flash, flashloader, flashverify, getbyte, getword,
getdword, help, info, jump, memtest, ping, reboot,
save, setbyte, setword, setdword, set, set gw, set hwrev,
set option, set initpwr, set ip, set mac, set mask, set mfgdate, set mfgtest,
set model, set serial, set server, set speed, set trial, show, reflash
IBoot> boot
Board Control Regs : 0x00000042
Loading PCMCIA Xilinx.
Waiting for Xilinx INIT pin low.
Waiting for Xilinx INIT pin high.
Writing data to Xilinx.
Waiting for Done High.
Relocating zImage from 000C0000 to A0008000 (len=00100000)
Proper ARM zImage ID found. Booting...
Uncompressing Linux............................................................... done, booting the kernel.
```